# installing an SSL on Azure ubuntu web server

Tags: azure

I have been trying to install an SSL Certificate on an Ubuntu Server running on a VPS.

Comment: What VPS? Do you have command line access? Can you upload the certificate via FTP? Do you have the certificate files? What web server? What have you tried so far?

Comment: After removing the unnecessary begging and "Any help will be appreciated", there is only a title left and a statement about what you have been trying. What is the problem? Can't you find the commands to type? Can't you reach your server. Did you type commands but don't get the result you expect. Please change your post to include a question with a question mark, for which the answer helps you forward. Include enough information in the post that we can actually answer that question (errors etc.)

Comment: I have it sorted, thanks. I did get the location if the CSR I created. located it on the root home.

Comment: I am glad to see that this has helped someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is what I did to resolve the issue.
1. I created a new endpoint (HTTPS - port 443) from my Microsoft Azure portal

On my Ubuntu VM terminal, I did the following.
To enable the SSL module in Apache2 you issue the command below

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

The you need to enable the site that would using the SSL

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

The directories /etc/ssl/certs and /etc/ssl/private are the default locations. If you install the certificate and key in another directory make sure to change SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile appropriately.
Add the following to your default-ssl file.

```
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/sslmate/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/sslmate/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/sslmate/example.comchain.crt


SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression off
```

now configured for HTTPS, restart the apache2 service to enable the new settings:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You might want to redirect all your HTTP request to HTTPS,  add the code below to your virtualHost file listening to port 80. It will redirect all HTTP request to the HTTPS (https://example.com)

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
 RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule /.* https://example.com/ [R]

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Generate the private key using openssl (install it if you don't have)

```
openssl genrsa -des3 2048 > privatekey.key
```

2) Generate the Certificate Signing Request (.CSR)

```
openssl req -new -key privatekey.key > mycsr.csr
```

3) Send the .csr to the certificate company (for example, certsign, godaddy, etc.)

4) You will receive the .CRT file from this company. Copy to your linux machine and setup your web server. On apache vhosts config:

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/local/ssl/privatekey.key // Generated Private Key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/local/ssl/receivedfile.crt // Received CRT
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/local/ssl/intermediate.crt // Certificate company sends this to you as well
```

5) Restart the web server

Comment: And when you're done, don't forget to check the configuration at https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/. Every score below B should be considered unsafe, and B already stands for Barely acceptable.